# Asp.net Core + Entity Framework 7 optimizations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Have a few questions about how EF7 + ASP.NET Core works...

1) Assume following tables:

```
Users PK=Id, etc.
Roles PK=Id, etc.
UserRoles FK=Users.Id,Roles.Id
```

When I do (pseudo) `_context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == "Bob").Include(...UserRoles...).ThenInclude(...Roles...)`, from the debug output, it appears EF7 is doing an optimization and only pulls back the minimal stuff it needs to fully populate a User POCO with Bob and his Roles? Its going to hit the database every time I run that statement? I.e. lets say the first time I run it, Bob has a role of "User". If I update the table to give him a role of "Admin", its going to re-pull everything? What about if I delete a roll, the next time I run that query, its going to re-sync everything?

2) It appears, that in EF7, you can't scaffold stored procs, correct? So I have a schema similar to this:

```
TableA
TableAToB
TableB
TableBToC
TableC
```

If you catch my drift, TableA has a M:M relationship with TableB (tied together with TableAToB) and TableB has a M:M relationship with TableC.

What I'm really after is all the TableC.Name values where TableA.Name="Blah", so I need to join all 5 of those tables together. If I do that in EF7 with table scaffolding, it seems like I'd have to do something similar to question #1 with .Include() to pull back all 5 tables and populate DbSets of all 5 tables when I really only want a single column from TableC. Is there a better way to do that?

3) Related to scenario #2, while I'm only interested in a subset of TableC as described, I'd like to cache it locally so I don't have to hit the DB on every request. I'd say pulling it once every 24 hours should be sufficient. Obviously I can't do that in the controller since a new controller is new'ed up every request. Is there a pattern for this common scenario?

Comment: (2) usually is called *query*. Use `select` to return the desired columns, `where` for filtering (the navigation properties allows you to use filter on any of the related tables).